# PHP if condition number issue

Tags: php

The php code is returing true in both cases show below. I dont know why?

```
<?php

$cid = 150;

if ($cid=100)
{
echo $cid;
echo "<BR>";
}

if ($cid==100)
{
echo "NEW";
echo "<BR>";
echo $cid;
echo "<BR>";
}

?>
```

The output is: 
100
NEW
100

Why is the if condition not working?

Comment: Because `=` is not the same as `==`.

Comment: Just simply compare your code line by line and you already see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first if-statement you are assigning `100` to `$cid`, not comparing. You're using a single `=` instead of `==`. So in the first statement `$cid` is set to `100`. When it comes to the second if-statement, `$cid` has a value of `100`. So the conditional evaluates in a truthy value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. :)